# Drop-down CSS navigation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, list, firefox, drop-down-menu, navigation

I'm working on getting my site up and running, and I've run into a problem with my drop-down navigation menu in Firefox.

I have been using the site in Chrome and it works fine, it is a simple setup of nested lists for the selections.  The options appear, but they are floating to the left instead of directly below their appropriate section.

CSS:

```
/*sub-menu navigation*/
nav.primary ul ul 
{
    opacity: 0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);

    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    background: #111111;

    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;

    min-width: 100%;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;
    transition: opacity 0.4s ease-out;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

nav.primary ul li:hover ul 
{
    opacity: 10;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);

    height: auto;
    overflow: auto;
}

nav.primary ul ul li 
{
    float: none;
    display: list-item;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #747474;
}

nav.primary ul ul li a 
{
    display: block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
   /*text-transform: none;*/
    font-family: 'LibbyRegular', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Menu HTML

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html#individual" title="individual">independent work</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="bigAndUgly.html">>> big and ugly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="iceworld.html">>> iceworld</a></li>
                        <li><a href="gordonsGotGame.html">>> gordon's got game</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html#team" title="team">team projects</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="blastrobots.html">>> blastrobots</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">>> ruined</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.html#scripting" title="scripting">scripting</a>

                <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">>> hero man (C#)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">>> CloneOut (lua)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">>> shotgun (unrealscript)</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a href="resume.html" title="resume">resume</a></li>
            </ul>
```

The site is http://lvsherman.com if you would like to test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your inner UL elements.

```
left: 0;
top: WHATEVER;
```